# Nested Scrollable Flexboxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a full height sidebar with tabbed content. Within the sidebar is a header with a company brand and a footer with tabs to switch between the content.

The content div has its own sticky header / footer with a scrollable subcontent div.

A working example can be seen in this gif: http://cl.ly/csW1 (this was done by hand manipulating the HTML elements) and with this [Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1e3msq1g/).

Psuedo-Code for this is:

Sidebar

- Header (Branding)
- Content (Tab Content)

  - Header (Tab Header)
  - **Scrollable Content** (Lists, Divs, etc. of content)
  - Footer (Tab Content Controls)
- Footer (Tab Controls)

My issue is that there's the real version contains a few extra div elements due to the way the content is loaded in (via knockout) which stops the nested flexboxes from scrolling content properly.

The broken (and real version) is in this [Real JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1e3msq1g/2/)

The CSS in question is here - see the jsfiddle for the full HTML structure:

```
#inspectorContainer {
    position:absolute;
    width:320px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:white;
}
#parent {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    background-color: limegreen;
}
#parent > header {
    flex: none;
    background-color: limegreen;
}
#parent > footer {
    flex: none;
}
.child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 0;
}
.child > .sticky {
    flex: none;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
.child > .contentblock {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you added more elements you messed the structure.

Basically,

1. (Optional) Get the item with the `contentblock` class, and remove the class.
2. Get the item with the `child` class, and replace all the classes with the `contentblock` class.
3. Get the item with the `tabs-content` class, and replace it with the `child` class.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#inspectorContainer {
  position:absolute;
  width:320px;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  background-color:white;
}
#parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background-color: limegreen;
}
#parent > header {
  flex: none;
  background-color: limegreen;
}
#parent > footer {
  flex: none;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
}
.child > .sticky {
  flex: none;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.child > .contentblock {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="inspectorContainer">
  <section id="parent">
    <header>Parent flex header</header>
    <div class="child">
      <!-- main-tab -->
      <div class="contentblock" id="main-tab">
        <!-- hard code for demo-->
        <div id="entities_list"></div>
        <div id="inspector-content">
          <div class="viewerMode-normal-selection">
            <div class="firecamera">
              <header class="sticky">Child flex header</header>
              <article>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
                <p>Lots of content.</p>
              </article>
              <footer class="sticky">Child flex footer</footer>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- layers-tab -->
      <div class="content insight-tab-content" id="layers-tab">
      </div>
      <!-- tools-tab -->
      <div class="content insight-tab-content" id="tools-tab">
      </div>
      <!-- events-tab -->
      <div class="content insight-tab-content" id="events-tab">
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>Parent flex footer</footer>
  </section>
  <footer class="footer">
    <ul class="tabs" id="inspector-tabs" data-tab="">
      <li id="tab-entities" class="tab-title active"><a href="#main-tab" class="insight-tab-title">Entities</a>
      </li>
      <li id="tab-layers" class="tab-title"><a href="#layers-tab" class="insight-tab-title">Layers</a>
      </li>
      <li id="tab-tools" class="tab-title"><a href="#tools-tab" class="insight-tab-title">Tools</a>
      </li>
      <li id="tab-alerts" class="tab-title"><a href="#events-tab" class="insight-tab-title">Alerts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```